Enable Checkbox "Expose Primary Key" with Geoserver RestAPI
Does not enable checkbox when using 
Hi,
i have a python script which creates workspace, datastore and a layer in a dockerized geoserver when the container is up'ed with docker compose.
The problem is, i want to enable this checkbox and have following RestAPI Command. It creates the datastore but does not check the box.
    datastore_data = f"""
    <dataStore>
        <name>{datastore_name}</name>
        <connectionParameters>
            <host>database</host>
            <port>5432</port>
            <database>xxx}</database>
            <schema>yyy</schema>
            <user>zzz</user>
            <passwd>123</passwd>
            <dbtype>postgis</dbtype>
            <exposePrimaryKeys>true</exposePrimaryKeys>
        </connectionParameters>
    </dataStore>
    """

Somebody has an idea, why its not working. The Documentation is not very good and i cant find answers online.
Cheers

The usual trick to working out anything to do with the GeoServer REST API is to set up whatever it is in the GUI and then do a GET request to see what is needed. In this case I get the following XML:
<connectionParameters>
   <entry key="schema">public</entry>
   <entry key="Evictor run periodicity">300</entry>
   <entry key="Max open prepared statements">50</entry>
   <entry key="encode functions">true</entry>
   ...
   <entry key="Expose primary keys">true</entry>
   ...

So I would go with that format, though yours might work if you use the correct key Expose primary keys.

Thanks so much. Also for the advice!!
